# best phrase or sentence to cheer up/celebrate somebody

Tags: phrase-request

At work, your colleague got back his sales revenues, or promotion.
Then, in this situation, you could say "what".

I want to know more expression when you have to celebrate, not the word "congratulation". Of course, it's the situation that happily saying.

Comment: Can you give more details about what is being celebrated by your colleague and what you want to express to them? Also, don’t put “what” in quotes. You would not say “what” in response to someone’s good news.

Comment: i got learn today! thanks.
And here's a situation you and i made a big at work. in this situation it's not proper words like congratulation. It would say better thanks for your efforts, thanks for your hard work. I know it's good expression but I always saying like that(thank you). It feels like too short for me. So my point is I want to a expression deeply and sincerely. switch to other expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You could say something like

> - Congratulations on your promotion.
> - Well-deserved
> - Great job/ good job
> - You worked hard and you truly deserve the promotion. Congratulations!